# how to pin point type layer details on map using ms4w map server

Tags: mapserver, map-point, ms4w

My aim is to create pin point on map and when click event on that pin point to show some details about that point (like shop name ,street name).

My point shape file is [image]

for rendering on the map i write bellow code.

```
LAYER
NAME "Siaya_towns"
DATA Siaya_towns
TYPE POINT
STATUS DEFAULT
CLASS
  COLOR 255 255 0
  OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
  SYMBOL "pin.png"
  SIZE 8  
END
END
```

I get the out put perfect.But i am not able to get the town name when we click on the pin point ...Please help me .how to achieve this.

Comment: Which tool do you use as a client?

Comment: sorry iam  new to this i am using ms4w for php

Comment: Do you want to display your layers in a web browser or a desktop client? Though whatever client you use, you need to activate the WMS getFeatureInfo service in mapserver then you can use QGIS for example to load your layer as WMS layer and use the 'identify features' tool to display a popup. You should dig more in the documentation, it is basic stuffs.

Comment: can you provide some links to that.or else a basic example

Comment: http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html

Comment: @nicolas i read the document done changes accordingly but it can't solve my problem

Comment: Which tool do you use to click on your pin points? Can you load your layer in QGIS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18043/discussion-between-nickle-and-nicolas-boisteault).

Comment: Edit the mapfile in your question to show the changes you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate getFeatureInfo service in mapserver.

Then you can display your layer via WMS protocol in [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html) for example.

And to finish you can add the WMSGetFeatureInfo control in OpenLayers. Look at the source code in [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html) :

```
<script>
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";

var map, info;

function load() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(143.834,-43.648,148.479,-39.573)
    });

    var political = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("State Boundaries",
        "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms", 
        {'layers': 'topp:tasmania_state_boundaries', transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: true}
    );

    var roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Roads",
        "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms", 
        {'layers': 'topp:tasmania_roads', transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: false}
    );

    var cities = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Cities",
        "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms", 
        {'layers': 'topp:tasmania_cities', transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: false}
    );

    var water = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Bodies of Water",
        "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms", 
        {'layers': 'topp:tasmania_water_bodies', transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: false}
    );

    var highlight = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Highlighted Features", {
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false, 
        isBaseLayer: false 
    });

    map.addLayers([political, roads, cities, water, highlight]); 

    info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}

</script>
```

Comment: i seen these when i pass my url its just shows blank page

Comment: You really have to make efforts to get you understood. Give examples or ways to reproduce your issue.

Comment: here are the zip files download it once and see readme.txt once http://sraossinc.net:7071/mapfiles/